# Django - field of language choices

Tags: python, django

I want to let users choose from languages they speak. Is there a Django built-in list of languages or should I get list of languages from another source?

For now:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)

class Language(models.Model):
    shortcut ...
    name ...
```

The languages field should only be able to list all languages user can speak.

Comment: Use one of the ISO 639 lists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_ISO_639_codes

Answer (score 4):

There's the [django-language-field](https://pypi.org/project/django-language-field/). Unfortunately, it's sorted by the language code instead of the language name.

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't have a build-in list of lenguages! You have to get your list of lenguages from other source! For example you might see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Comment: (Actually [there is](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.2/django/conf/global_settings.py#L51-L148) and it's in the [documentation since at least v1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#languages))

Comment: @bufh: it's not list of all possible languages. It's list of only languages that Django is translated to.